# 301 Redirects when change URL in WordPress database

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I needed to update the URL of a site from .com to .blog. The site is hosted at WP Engine with DNS at Cloudflare.

I added the new domain to Cloudflare, pointed it to WP Engine, added the domain in the WP Engine domain manager, then changed the HOME and SITE URL to reflect the .com to .blog switch.

I know that I can use Page Rules in Cloudflare to redirect .site.com/* to site.blog, but I need to make sure that all wildcard URLs resolve to their new .blog/[path].

Because I don't have two instances of WordPress, one with .com and one with .blog, it's not a one-to-one relationship. I simply changed the .com to .blog in the database and removed .com from the domain manager at WP Engine. Now, that the .com domain has been removed and the forward set up in Cloudflare, I need it to wildcard to pick up the path of the new .blog. There is no .htaccess file on the .com domain, because the .htaccess file now belongs to the .blog domain and install.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: If you still have `.com` you could use some [`.htaccess`](http://pastebin.com/XjaDRrMB). Major hosts offer panels where you can set up wildcard redirects to new domains in case you don't have the `.com` hosted anymore..

Comment: Whom did you buy the .com domain from? Some domain managers allow HTTP redirect without needing hosting account.